# Cannot get value from Mongo DB Rails Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rake, nokogiri

Hope you could help me with the issue that I cannot find an answer.
I have this app and trying to retrieve & update the value of record in DB.

My rake command in rails app looks like this:

```
task :nokogiri => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

  data = doc.at_css(".lister-list")
  movies = data.css('.titleColumn')
  current_time = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    movies.each do |movie|

      headline = movie.text.strip
      found = Movie.where("title" => headline).first

      if found.nil?
        title = Movie.new
        title._id = BSON::ObjectId.new
        title.title = headline
        title.current_time = current_time.to_s
        title.save
        puts "Record created"
      else
      #  arr =  found.to_a.to_json
       # puts arr.title
        puts found.title
        puts "Record exist"
      end
    end
end
```

The issue is that I can output "arr" object to console, but I am not able to check title field. I keep getting:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #<String:0x007f68589d93e8>
```

What do I do wrong here? How I could update the record with current_time?

p.s. I am new on rails, so your help would help me a lot and you are the last ones who can help me.

THANK YOU!

Edited: Answer was simple, with function where, we have to limit results and put it **.first**. Then we can get object values as usual **found.title**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else` branch you say this:

```
arr =  found.to_a.to_json
```

`to_json` returns a `String`. Then you say:

```
puts arr.title
```

but there is no `String#title` method so you get a `NoMethodError`. Perhaps you mean to say:

```
puts found.title
```

Also, do you really mean to say `found.to_a.to_json` rather than `found.to_json`? That `to_a` call just wraps `found` in a single element array.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried many ways, this is only the last version of code. However, your solution worked. At the start, I wasn't using ".first" method for found object, this is why I was getting error on "puts found.title". Issue is resolved Finally.